# sorl-thumbnail resize and add background

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using sorl-thumbnail and I want to resize an image to 200x200. Let's say the image will then be 160x200, because its not square. How can I add a white background (or borders) so that the resulting imagefile is 200x200?
Is this possible with sorl-thumbnail or can I add this functionality?

Best
Jacques

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's a little late, but you can find your answer in margin property:

In Short:

```
{% thumbnail something.image "200x200" as image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" style="padding:{{ image|margin:"200x200" }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

... and do not forget to set

```
img { background-color: #fff; }
```

Details from documentation: http://thumbnail.sorl.net/template.html#margin

Answer (score -1):

I'm confused by what you mean about resizing the image to 200x200 and then to 160x200. Do you just want the image to be cropped proportionally, based on it's longest side? If so, you can do this:

```
{% thumbnail something.image "200x200" as image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ something.name }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

which should give you the behavior you were looking for in terms of cropping.

Are you looking to actually overlay a border over the image or do would creating a border via CSS be appropriate?

```
img {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

If instead you actually want to change the image itself, I am sure you can modify the source code (which you can [fork on GitHub here](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail)) to do what you need.

I can also recommend [django-photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) as an alternative if you want to do things like watermarks, etc... I have found it to be really nice when it comes to doing site wide image modifications, compared to sorl.

Comment: what I meant is: I'm using proportional cropping to 200x200 (similar to your first example). But when I'm having an image that isn't square this code will produce a new imagefile with a geometry of, for example, 160x200. Is there a way to add a 200x200 background to this image?

Comment: I want all imagefiles to be the same size (200x200), but without changing the aspect ratio of the original images and without any cropping.

You can also think of adding borders to the resized images (with sizes like 160x200, 195x200, 200x130, 200x50, ...) in order to make these files all the same size of 200x200.

Comment: Now, I found this:
[link](http://taylanpince.com/blog/posts/sorlthumbnail-and-custom-processors/)
This pad-function seems to just do what I need,but as I'm quite new to Django, I have no idea how to add this to my code and how to use it in a template. It also looks like the code depends on older versions of sorl-thumbnail.

I really don't know what to do.

Best 
Jacques